# SAS . When does output override default output in a data step?

Tags: sas

I am confused with the `output` statement . Here are two programs that both have output .

**1) Program one . Produces 3 observations, just as I expect it, `output` overwrites the default `data step output`**

```
data test ;
infile datalines ; 
input type $ @ ; 
if type='a' then do;
input money ; 
output ; 
end;
datalines ;
a 100
b 200
a 500
a 400
x 500
v 500
;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

---

**2) Program two . Produces 6 observations . Why doesn't  `output`  overwrite this data step ?**

```
data test ;
infile datalines ; 
input type $ @ ; 
if type='a' then input money ; 
output ; 
datalines ;
a 100
b 200
a 500
a 400
x 500
v 500
;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

**Why `output` in the first case does the job but in the second case it does not ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first program, output is part of a conditionally executed **do group** because it is between `if type='a' then do;` and `end;`. Therefore it only executes if type equals 'a'. In the second program, output is not part a do group at all, so it executes for all observations, thus all observations are output.

Comment: +1 Thank you. But with this logic, the first program shoudl also have 6 observations. Here is why :  because `input type $ @ ; ` comes before the `if-then` block and therefore executes regardless of the `if-then` outcome. So, before we even get to the `if-then` block the program has already executed `input type $ @ ; `  Even if the `if-then` block turns out to be false, we do `input` the `type`. So ALL `type` values are read, and therefore the first program should have had 6 observations, right ?

Comment: Incorrect. Although 6 records are read, only 3 are output based on the evaluation of the if condition. If you take out the explicit `output` statement in program 1, you'll see 6 observations, but only 3 will have a value in the money field.